# When localization is indecomposable

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, sheaf-theory

We know that if $R $ is a domain then any localization of $R $ at any multiplicative subset of $R $ is indecomposable, that is, has no non trivial idempotents.  Now let $R $ be a commutative ring with 1 that  has no non trivial idempotents. I am looking for an additional condition on $R $ under which any localization $R_r $  to be indecomposable for each non nilpotent element $r\in R $.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is true if and only if $R$ has a unique minimal prime ideal.

Comment: @Mohan, thank you, can you expain a little more. Especialy for the  only part.

Comment: @Mohan, I can prove that if $R $ has finite many minimal prime ideals, then the property holds. But I cannt  prove the converse. Are you sure that the converse is true? Can you give some hints?

Comment: I apologize. I am `Noetherian' person and there are only finitely many minimal primes. I should have stressed that.